# Existence of an element $\xi\in \mathbb R$ such that $m(A\cap (B+\xi))>0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ and $B$ are two positive Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb R,$ that is, $m(A)>0$ and $m(B)>0$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R.$ I want to show that, there exists an element $\xi\in \mathbb R$ such that $m(A\cap (B+\xi))>0.$

**My approach:** I am unable to prove it rigorously, but I have an idea. Note that, since $m(A)>0$ by Lebesgue density theorem there exists a density point $a\in A,$ that is
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \frac{m\left(A\cap (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\right)}{2\epsilon}=1.$$ Also for the case $B$, since $m(B)>0$, there exists a density point $b \in B$. Now consider $\xi=a-b$. Now if I translate $B$ to $\xi$ and then intersects with $A$ then we get the intersection as positive measurable, that is, $m(A\cap (B+\xi))>0.$ But I am unable to show that how exactly $m(A\cap (B+\xi))>0.$ Up to existence of density points $a$ and $b$ are all good but I am not able to show it rigorously that $m(A\cap (B+\xi))>0.$

Please help me to show this. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: If are familiar with convolution of functions $m(A\cap(x+B))=\int\mathbb{1}_A(t)\mathbb{t}_{B+x}\,dt=\int\mathbb{1}_A(t)\mathbb{1}(t-x)\,dt=\int\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_{-B}(x-t)\,dt=\mathbb{1}_A*\mathbb{1}_{-B}(x)$

Answer (score 1):

You have all the major tools figured out.  Now just evaluate $\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}\frac{m(A\cap (B+\xi) \cap (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon))}{2\epsilon}$ by using $$m(E_1\cap E_2) = m(E_1) + m(E_2) - m(E_1\cup E_2)$$ for $E_1 = A \cap (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ and $E_2 = (B+\xi) \cap (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Essentially the same argument with more words and fewer formulas: If $A$ contains 90% of the interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ and $B+\xi$ also contains 90% of the same interval, then the intersection $A\cap(B+\xi)$ contains at least 80% of that same interval.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree that's a fair summary of the problem.  I'm often torn between higher-level and lower-level solutions, but when OP specifies they're having problems with rigor, I tend to present lower-level solutions.

Comment: I agree; for purposes of rigor, one wants something like your argument. But for finding the idea (before getting to rigor), it may help to have something like my comment, which may be just a quantitative version of what the OP intuitively felt.